# How to block a windows port

Tags: c#

I want to block a windows port using C# or any other way i.e it should not be used
by others until i release the block how to do it. Is there any free s/w available to block 
a port (tcp,udp etc). Please help me to solve this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you bind to this port, nobody else can bind to it. That's the only way to block others.

Comment: Firewalls do this by mucking about in the network stack. Somewhere between the network driver and where the operating system decides to hand the packet to an application, the firewall looks at it and might drop it there.  Applications can still try to listen for traffic, but they won't get any.

Comment: Yes, firewalls go much deeper than normal application layer software.