# Block all network ports except one in Windows (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I am creating a .NET console application in C#. This application is a small script which uses the OpenVPN CLI to automatically connect to a VPN server without any manual steps.

I want to block all the network ports from the device, except the one which is being used by the OpenVPN CLI. E.g. port 1194. Can this be done in Windows and how could one achieve this? I tried something with the `netsh`command by changing the default gateway of the system, but that resulted in a full internet block. E.g `Process.Start` with `netsh interface ipv4 set address name="Wi-Fi 3" static 192.168.1.15 255.255.255.0 127.0.0.1`.

I couldn't find a command/code to block all the ports except one, so any help in this would be appreciated.

Comment: To block ports you'd need to make changes to the windows firewall settings. But why do you want to block every other port? What if a user wants to google something (so he'd need port 443 and potentially 80 as well)?

Comment: @MindSwipe, this will be useful if the VPN connection drops and needs a reconnect. This will ensure the user only passes traffic through the VPN tunnel, therefore I only want one port (the VPN port) open.

Comment: Don't most VPNs work by updating windows networking to make it prefer to use a virtual interface that happens to represent the tunnel? If so, it would block all network use *when the VPN is up*, since so far as windows is concerned, it's all just network traffic.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to block a windows port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1878820/how-to-block-a-windows-port)